# MYSQL Select form users table where half is female and half male

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way, to select from a users table with a field named `'gender'`
 where 50% of the result have the value 'female' and 50% 'men'.
This is my actual query:

```
SELECT *
          FROM geo_sorted_users_de_prod AS r1 JOIN
               (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                             (SELECT MAX(id)
                                FROM geo_sorted_users_de_prod)) AS id )
                AS r2
         WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
         AND Length(descr) > 10
         ORDER BY r1.id ASC
         LIMIT 11
```

I  want to avoid, to run 2 queries.

Comment: you could trivially do it with 2 queries that you `union` together: one to get some random males, the other to get some random females, and limit each to 1/2 of what you want in the way of result rows.

Comment: Are you trying to get a random sample of the users but with an equal number of male/female results?

Comment: Nope. Not equal. I have a Limit of 11. So 5 men, and 6 women.

Comment: I think the comment to your original post is probably the best idea. It would be almost the same as what you're doing now.

Comment: Something like:  (SELECT * FROM geo_sorted_users_de_prod WHERE gender=female LIMIT 6) UNION (SELECT * FROM geo_sorted_users_de_prod WHERE gender=male LIMIT 5)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `YOUR_TABLE` is your query with the aditional `random_id` but without `LIMIT 11`

***Step 1***: assign `row_number()`. In mySql doesnt have it so you need use variables to emulate.

```
SELECT t.*, 
     @rownum := if(gender = @gender, @rownum + 1, 1) AS RowNumber,
     @gender := gender  
FROM YOUR_TABLE t, 
     (SELECT @rownum := 0, @gender = '') r
ORDER BY gender, random_id
```

***Step 2***: Select how many of each category you want. And because you `order by random_id` each category will select random rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM Step1
WHERE (gender = 'male' and RowNumber <= 5)
   OR (gender = 'female' and RowNumber <= 6)
```